# Failed to find:com.android.support:design:26.0.1

Tags: android, android-sdk-tools, android-developer-api

I want to use `AppBarLayout` and `CoordinateLayout` for my Android project so, I added `compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.1'` to the gradle dependencies. But I'm getting an error all the time as `Failed to find:com.android.support:design:26.0.1.` and if I try choose the install repository and sync again option, nothing is happening.

I think my SDK is pretty much update!

How to get rid of it and be able to add the layouts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/support-library/setup.html), make sure you have include a maven section with the https://maven.google.com endpoint.

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your gradle file:

```
repositories {
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting with Gradle 4.0 (works with upcoming Android Studio 3) you are also able to just add:

```
 repositories {
     ...
     google()
 }
```

[See official Gradle docs](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/artifacts/dsl/RepositoryHandler.html#google())

Answer (score 0):

Another reason for this is not upgrading to the latest gradle, but if you are using AS 2.3.3 you need a work-around as well.

I am targeting/compiling with

```
android version 26
```

First update your gradle: 
https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html
says to

```
update the URL in gradle-wrapper.properties as follows:

distributionUrl=\
 https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all.zip
```

I also had to add:

```
maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com'
            // Alternative URL is 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/'
        }
```

(google() does not work for me before updating)
and run

```
./gradlew --stop
```

from project root
This caused the manual gradle download to start.

I had to copy the downloaded folder

```
(~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-4.1-rc-1-all/gradle-4.1-rc-1)
```

to

```
"/Applications/Android Studio app/Contents/gradle/gradle-4.1-rc-1"
```

AS may ask you to update this  in the gradle console window as well (it will provide a link where you can choose the new version)

I also had to update any library entries:

```
 compile project(path: ':<my-lib>', configuration: 'default')
```

The workaround involves downgrading the plugin to

```
 classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.3'
```

as per
https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/294
Finally, it builds..... sheesh.